# Checking padding-top: env (safe-area-inset-top);

Tags: html, css, ios, xcode, webview

Tell me please. I am making a website that can be logged in both from a browser and my application on ios 14 (webview is used internally).
How can I make a check on a safe area.

```css
#block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

It is necessary to make it so that from the browser `padding-top` is `10px` and from the application, on the device where there is a safe-area `padding-top` was `env(safe-area-inset-top)`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you need a different `padding-top` for the mobile version and the desktop version?

Comment: @TomGroot What is not clear in my question?

Comment: Do you need a different `padding-top` for smaller screens (mobile version) and bigger screens (desktop version)? If that is the case maybe have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: @TomGroot What are you talking about? Do you understand what an env safe-area is?

Comment: I also cannot get env(safe-area-inset) to work in ios webview

Answer (score 0):

```
#block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top, 10px);
}
```

`env()` permits a fallback value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: calc(10px + env(safe-area-inset-top));
}
```

This should work.With `10px` by default and adding `safe-area-inset` in ios devices

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a media query for your specific screen size, like so:

```css
#block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  #block {
    padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="block">
</div>
```